# Installing 64-bit Windows on Intel core i3 560

Tags: windows-7, cpu, 64-bit, 32-bit

I've been asked to install Windows 10 on someone's computer and when I wanted to check whether to install 32-bit or 64-bit, I noticed something, that the computer has 8 GB of RAM, but was running 32-bit windows all the time. That computer is not mine and was bought in a store by someone not as tech savvy, so yeah, they've been fooled. I've been doing a little research and I came up to this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/122535/intel-core-i3-cpu-is-not-64-bit and according to that, i3's support 64-bit windows (if I understood correctly). However, this computer has Intel Core i3 560 model, which is very old and I cannot find out if they support 64-bit too.

So, do they support 64-bit windows, and if yes, can I install them normally or do I need to do something special?

http://ark.intel.com/products/50177/Intel-Core-i3-560-Processor-4M-Cache-3_33-GHz this is the processor. On this site it says Instruction Set: 64-bit. Does that mean it supports the 64-bit windows? Thank you.

Comment: Based on that Intel product page, the processor is capable of a 64 bit environment.

Comment: Thank you. Wasn't sure what Instruction set means. Also, found out that it supports EM64T feature, which is also required for windows 10 64-bit so I supposed that it does indeed support 64-bit, thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the processor has 64-bit support.

This processor family is a little old, it would be good you check the compatibility of other devices with the Microsoft tool before install Windows 10.

This [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583) has the Get Windows 10 tool and it checks the compatibility.